# Intersection graphs of 2-element subsets

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am interested in the intersection graphs of $\binom{X}{2}$, i.e. the set of all 2-element subsets of a (finite) set $X$.

[**Motivation**: One can represent every simple graph with $n$ vertices by an assignment of 0 or 1 to the vertices of the intersection graph of $\binom{[n]}{2}$. This is a somehow more "natural" (= "coordinate free") representation of a graph than the usual adjacency matrix.]

Especially I wonder

> - In which (other) contexts are/were these graphs investigated?
> - How can they be characterized abstractly?
> - And do they have a name, thus being characterized?

Comment: What's unnatural about the adjacency matrix? Regarded as an operator $\mathbb{R}^V \to \mathbb{R}^V$ it's perfectly coordinate-free. 

Comment: The complement is a Kneser graph.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^V$ supposed to be? (I always regarded the adjancency matrix as a function $[n]^2 \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$.)

Comment: @Butch: I'll provide a labelled picture. And I've been wrong about the neighbours forming a cycle, so I deleted that part of my question.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Googling for "adjacency matrix operator" I found this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270058/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-adjacency-matrix-as-a-linear-operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual name of your graph is $L(K_n)$, the **line graph** of the complete graph $K_n$. The line graphs of complete graphs have also been called **triangular** graphs, as I just learned moments ago from the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph .